# How to catch the click event from the axis ticks jqplot, highcharts,flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, highcharts, jqplot

I want to be able to catch the clicked event that is hooked to all the axis ticks.
here is what i have done so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/grVFk/5074/

If anyone knows how to do that with any of the charting plugins can kindly share.

thanks

Comment: how did you put up that chart in jsfiddle??

Comment: well i have anccount there so i can upload it things there. well u can also continue to work on mine or u create an account there and upload ur own files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the plot isn't plain HTML. So there is no `a` tag. And the plot itself do not provide you with an api to catch the `click` event on an axis tick.

What you can do is to select the axis tick manually with jQuery and add a `click` event:

```
$('.highcharts-axis tspan').each(function(){
    var label = $(this),
        value = label.text();
    if(categoryLinks[value]) {
        label.click(function(){
            // you' free to what you want...
            alert('could link to another page: ' + categoryLinks[value]);
        });
    }
});
```

And there is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/scheffield/grVFk/5090/

Comment: Thanks very much.that is exactly what i wanted. But i can i do thesame way with jqplot?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response .i would really prefer to use jqplot because it is free. so i was asking if there is also a way to hook a click event to axis tick and also catch them exactly as u just did  for highcharts. thanks

Comment: Mh, i don't think so since they use `canvas` in jqplot and not `svg` as they do in highcharts.

Comment: ok  thanks. i wonder whether it is possible with flot or do u know any other javascript chartting plugin that can allow us to implement such functionality? you have been of very great help to me . i really much appreciate it.

Comment: @fon, I think you are asking how to add click event on plotted bar, right?. Here  is what I have done ,                           $('#you-id-under-which-you-plot-the-bar-diagram').bind("jqplotDataClick", function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
  return window.location.href = "www.google.com";
}); You can refer to http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html

Comment: jqplot uses `div`s to render axes so you can use the same approach `$('.jqplot-xaxis-tick').each(function(){...`

Comment: Also, for jqplot, you'll need to change the z-index on the access because it sits behind the canvas normally and won't get the click events: `.jqplot-axis { z-index: 1000 }`