# jqplot how to make bar graph clickable that links to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I've tried playing around with jqplot to create bar chart that can be clicked and then will redirect user to another page together with label value as url parameters but so for no luck to make a link. This what I have done.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

         var ticks = [ 'SCAN', 'SGON', 'TERM', 'TRAN'];
         var arrBranchId = ['08270K08001', '08298K08003', '12026K12003','14123K14003'];
         var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1',[[0,0,0,1],[2,4,2,5],[0,0,0,1],[0,5,0,1]], {           
         seriesDefaults: {
                 renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                 rendererOptions: { fillToZero: true },
                 pointLabels: { show: true }
             },

             series: [{label:'08270K08001'},{label:'08298K08003'},{label:'12026K12003'},{label:'14123K14003'}],

             legend: {
                 show: true,
                 placement: 'ne'
             },
             highlighter: {
             show: false,

             },
              cursor: {
                show: true
              },
             axes: {

                 xaxis: {
                     renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                     ticks: ticks
                 },

                 yaxis: {
                     renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                     pad: 1.05,
                     tickOptions: { formatString: '%d' }
                 }
             }
         });
     });
```

- How should I make a link to the bar for example localhost/webCharts/branch.aspx?branchId=08270K08001

Also tried this [How to catch the click event from the axis ticks jqplot, highcharts,flot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699541/how-to-catch-the-click-event-from-the-axis-ticks-jqplot-highcharts-flot), changed the function to become

```
$('.jqplot-xaxis-tick').each(function(){
            var label = $(this),
                value = label.text();
            if(categoryLinks[value]) {
                label.click(function(){

                    alert('could link to another page: ' + categoryLinks[value]);
                });
            }
        });
```

but nothings happen when user click. Am i missing something here? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured a way to make the bar clickable and link to another page by using window.location as follows

```
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data){
                window.location = 'branchDetails.aspx?appId='+ticks[**pointIndex**]+"&branchId="+arrBranchId[**seriesIndex**];          
        });
```

Noted : the array ticks[ ] and arrBranchId[ ] is already defined at  $(document).ready(function() { ..... }. So I just passed the arrays with **pointIndex** and **seriesIndex**. Thank you very much everyone

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for a solution but I found your question while researching the same problem. I just figured out how to make it work. Based on your code you should add a function something like this:

```
$('#Chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    window.parent.location.href = 'YOURURL.aspx?id=' + arrBranchId[pointIndex];
});
```

Hopefully this will help you or someone else.

Comment: yes thanks for the idea. Seems like it is quite similar with the one that i had written on above :-D.

Comment: Ha, I guess I didn't read far enough down the page! That would have saved me some time! :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove your each loop and use jqplot binding method, jqplotDataClick:

```
// replace chart1 with your div ID
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',
function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    // data contains the data point value, play with it
    // NOTE it may contain an array and not a string
    alert(data);
});
```

In the example above I'm using alert(data) you can use the data value
to do anything else, ie redirect the user to a URL containing with the value
passed as a parameter

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/JWhmQ/

Comment: thanks, but how do I pass label as URL parameter? i have the label (series) value and would like to pass it to the other page. Example  localhost/webCharts/branch.aspx?labelValue=08270K08001. is it possible?

Comment: sure you can, did you look at my example on jsfiddle? just replace alert(data) with your link and use data as param value

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet to get the click event !

```
// Bind a listener to the "jqplotDataClick" event.  Here, simply change
  // the text of the info3 element to show what series and ponit were
  // clicked along with the data for that point.
  $('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick',
    function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {alert('clicked')
      $('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
    }
  );
```

Check out this demo [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/tQvCX/1/)

Comment: @mhn why ? it didn't helped you ? Please do suggest what else you want to implement it correctly !

Comment: Many thanks @Rahul Gupta, but is it possible for me to take label (series) value? What parameter should I use? thanks again.

Comment: I have updated my jsfiddle, now on clicking the graph you would be able to get the values, refer this link: http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/tQvCX/4/

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier method..
Keep it simple like this:

```
   $('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick', 
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                /* To open in a NEW window use: */
                /* window.open(data[2]); */
                /* To open in the same window use: */
                window.location.href='ErrorView3.php';
            }
  );
```